# How to send large attachments?

Tags: java, c#, email

Say I have an account on Yahoo. They limit the attachment size I can send, although they don't limit the size of the mails I can get. How do I send large attachments?

I successfully sent (via java or c#) emails, and used google-drive (web) to send large attachments (174M), but how do I combine it? I haven't found anything that says how to add to google drive and send it.

I saw some sites that enable you to send large files, but the problem is I want the files in the email server (Yahoo/GMAIL ), not on anonymous site (and I haven't found a sites that send email, only sites that store themselves). How do I do it?

Can I send the mails via telnet somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, use [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/) in your application.

Before sending email, upload your file to Google Drive and send the link to the uploaded file.

Comment: Do I send a link, or the attachment? I want the attachment on yahoo servers, not google.
And do I really can only use google drive? I remember having problems with it in java/C#...

Comment: Physically the file will be stored on the Google Drive. As Yahoo limits attachment size I doubt that would be possible to upload a file to Yahoo that is bigger than allowed. Other file hosting companies also have their API, for instance: http://www.mediafire.com/developers/  And as far as I know Yahoo does not provide any API to solve the task you described.

Comment: Yahoo limits the file size they send, but also the file size they can get? If I remember correctly, I sent via google drive (web)  a big file. Also - yahoo provides 1 TB. Is there any other company providing 1 TB, and don't limit the attachment size?

Comment: When you send file via Google Drive you are not sending the file, you are sending the link to the file located on Google Drive. As far as I know Yahoo does not have something like that. And for Yahoo if you are trying to attach a big file that exceeds the sending file size limits you will get an error.

Comment: @user3779142 and I am not sure that Yahoo 1 TB storage (Flickr?) can be used like Google Drive.

Comment: So I have have no option getting a bigger file than the attachment limit? Are there other (free) emails where you can?
And just see under "Features -> Free version" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Mail

Comment: As an option you can split your big files to smaller ones to send them. And receiver will compose the big file from its parts. It can be done with multi-volume archives for example.